# Unicode with knitr and Rmarkdown

Tags: r, unicode, knitr, r-markdown

Is there a set of best practices or documentation for working with Unicode in knitr and Rmarkdown? I can't seem to get any glyphs to show up properly when knitting a document.

For example, this works in the console (in Rstudio):

```
> cat("\U2660   \U2665  \U2666  \U2663")
♠   ♥   ♦   ♣
```

But when knitting I get this:

- HTML

[image]

- Word

[image]

Comment: `sessionInfo()` please.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like an encoding issue specific to Windows, and may be related to this issue: https://github.com/hadley/evaluate/issues/59 Unfortunately we have to wait for a fix in base R, but if you don't have to use `cat()`, and this expression is a *top-level* expression in your code chunk (e.g. not inside a for-loop or if-statement), I guess this may work:

```
knitr::asis_output("\U2660   \U2665  \U2666  \U2663")
```

It passes the character string directly to **knitr** and bypasses `cat()`, since **knitr** cannot reliably catch multibyte characters written out by `cat()` on Windows -- it depends on whether the characters can be represented by your system's native encoding.

Answer (score 11):

## Unicode: Inline

```
Phew, that was close `r knitr::asis_output("\U1F605  \U2660   \U2665  \U2666  \U2663")`
```

[image]

## Unicode: Block

````
```{r, echo=FALSE} 
knitr::asis_output("Phew, that was close \U1F605  \U2660   \U2665  \U2666  \U2663")
```
````

[image]

## The [emo](https://github.com/hadley/emo) package

Unfortunately, this package isn't yet on CRAN, but it can be installed with `devtools::install_github("hadley/emo")`

```
emo::ji("face")
```

There are some more examples [here](https://github.com/hadley/emo#example)

Answer (score 10):

For anyone else who came across this after trying to get emoji support in Rstudio/Rmarkdown documents, another possible issue is that if the file encoding isn't set to UTF-8, the resulting compiled document won't support emojis either.

In order for emoji to work in Rmarkdown, you must [change the file encoding of the Rmd document](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding). Go to File -> Reopen with encoding, then select UTF-8.

Once you have ensured the file is open in UTF-8 encoding, you should be able to compile with emoji support.

You should even be able to paste emoji from a browser directly into the document.

It is probably a good idea to change the default encoding for all files to UTF-8 so that you don't have to deal with this issue again.