# use of unicode in R markdown

Tags: r, unicode, markdown

I have a function that prints some unicode characters to the console. This works perfectly fine when executed in the console, but when I run the same command in a chunk in an R markdown document some of the characters don't display correctly.

Here is a toy example:

```
test <- function() cat("\U003BC \U002260 \U003C0\n")
```

when run in the R console shows μ ≠ π, but when run in a chunk it does the mu correctly but not the other two, see attached screenshot.

[image]

Update: thanks for the replies so far. It seems that this is an issue with base R on Windows. The suggestion to use

```
knitr::asis_output(test1())
```

works. I also tried to use the chunk option results='asis', but this does not work, so somehow there is a difference between these two.

At least I now have a way to do what I want, except that I need to rewrite a number of routines to return the character string instead of using cat to print it.

Comment: In my setup it works as expected

Comment: This also works on my machine when I'm knitting. Is it only in the Viewer, or does knitting changes something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode with knitr and Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153072/unicode-with-knitr-and-rmarkdown)