# emo::ji won't render in knitted documents

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, knitr, emoji

I want to insert a few [emojis](https://github.com/hadley/emo) into my `rmarkdown` document.

```r
devtools::install_github("hadley/emo")
library(emo)
emo::ji('turtle')
#
```

However, when I knit my document in the emojis won't render.
In this example the chunk render doesn't work but the inline one does:

````r
    Example for not rendering:

    ``` {r}
    library(emo)
    emo::ji('smile')
    ```

    Inline example:
    `r emo::j('smile')`
````

[image]
But then here the inline doesn't work as well:

```r
<font color='skyblue'>*Hey, you! Marine biologist! I have need of your services!  
A sea turtle begins its life amidst great danger, and not very many of them make it to the water. See, I'm working on a big budget movie - think "Saw", but with turtles. Anyway, let's make some realistic numbers of turtles for me to... **keep alive.***</font> `r emo::ji('turtle')`
```

[image]

I've updated everything I could think of (R, Rstudio, all markdown-related packages) but alas.

Comment: On Linux the  works for me in both cases. The  produces only an empty box in RStudio, but works when I open the HTML file with a browser.

Comment: I use Windows 10. Neither emoji appears when I open in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of searching I found that the problem was with the native encoding of my session. As presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52059455/4986143), I did File -> Reopen with Encoding... and selected `UTF-8`, and for good measure selected `UTF-8` to be the default in the future. Knitted the file - worked like a charm.